# How to handle Parse.com's transformation of a HTTP error to a NSError?

Tags: parse-platform, httpresponse, nserror

I'm calling a 3rd-party server from Cloud Code. The former can return HTTP errors which I want to pass to a calling iOS app.

I'd like my iOS app to handle the HTTP error details when the 3rd-party server throws a HTTP exception.

The only way I've found so far is to treat those exceptions as a Cloud Code "success"!

Is there a better way?

An example
When the 3rd-party server returns a HTTP 400, "Missing Name" error:

From my Cloud Code I can call:

```
response.error(httpResponse);
```

Then in Swift I can parse this with:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("func", withParameters:[]) {
    (result, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // handle success
    } else {
        // handle error
        // Parse.com has wrapped the originating http error with a status code of 141 so I'll need to JSON parse the deeper fields to get 400 & "Missing Name".
    }
```

But, instead, from Cloud Code, I can call `response.success(httpResponse)` and then do this:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("func", withParameters:[]) {
    (result, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      let result = result as! [String:AnyObject]
      let status = result["status"]     
      let text = result["text"] as! String
      // status will be 400
      // text will be "Missing Name"
    } else {
       // handle Parse.com's 141s
    }
```

This makes field parsing more accessible. But I'm handling HTTP errors along with successful calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can potentially customize the error message/data but unfortunately you cannot change the error code 141 if you use `response.error()` method. See [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/custom-error-response-codes-for-cloud-code)